# Connection to a Unix Based OS from ASP.net application

Tags: asp.net, unix, connection

I'd like to create a program that would connect my asp.net application to unix based system and run some command from the application.

Is there anyway to do this?

Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  The best approach would probably be to write a simple web service on the Unix OS in Perl or Python or something similar, that service would execute the command, then return any data back to you.

You can then consume that web service from your asp.net application quite easily.

There are probably many other ways to do it, but that would be my approach.  Assuming the app did not take a long time to execute.